# In table, how to hide borders and merge different cells?

Tags: tables, longtable

Trying to convert this table 1 to the table 2 format,
[image: Table 1]

Table 2 (single table), merging the cells 1x1 & 1x2, merging the entire 3rd column and hiding the borders, and again merging the 1x4 & 1x5, with defined column width and row height.
[image: Table 2]

Any ideas or suggestions apart from this method are also welcome

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline & Column A & & & Column B \\
\hline i & Wind & & a & Monsoon \\
\hline ii & Anemometer & & b & Cyclone \\
\hline iii & Hurricane, Typhoon & & c & Measures speed of Wind \\
\hline iv & Mausam & & d & Moving air \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are not adept at making tables in LaTeX, you can try Excel add-in **Excel2LaTeX**.

Comment: There is also [tablesgenerator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

Comment: Noticed that you have edited your question with new requirements (defined column width and row height), I have edited my answer accordingly. Maybe it is better if you use **EDIT** to show what's the new part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different from [user187803](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/263192/user187803)'s answer with the third column merged (though it makes no difference).

#### EDIT

- Thanks to NBur, I removed unnecessary packages;
- Now the column width and arraystretch can be set. The width of column is set by the value after `p`. The height of the table should be automatically set as you see the word wrap is on. But you can also set the arraystretch freely here.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \bgroup
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% <-- array stretch for the table
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
      \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Column A}} & \multirow{5}[10]{*}{} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Column B}} \\
      \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} i & Wind &   & a & Monsoon \\
      \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} ii & Anemometer &   & b & Cyclone \\
      \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} iii & Hurricane, Typhoon &   & c & Measures speed of Wind \\
      \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} iv & Mausam, longer and longer and longer &   & d & Moving air \\
      \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
    \end{tabular}%
  \egroup
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Actually I made this table using [Excel2LaTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex?lang=en) which is rather convenient.

Comment: Maybe you can remove `tabularx` and `booktabs`, since you don't uses these packages.

Comment: @NBur Thanks for your advice and I am editing it.

Comment: Since I'm new to the community I'm not aware of how to use edit and thanks for the input @Teddy van jerry it was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\cline` and `\multicolumn`.
**EDIT**
For defined column widths, you can use `p{width}` in the column definition.
For defined row heights, you can redefine `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \sffamily
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}|l|l|}
        \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Column A}} & & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Column B}} \\
        \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} i & Wind & & a & Monsoon \\
        \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} ii & Anemometer & & b & Cyclone \\
        \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} iii & Hurricane, Typhoon & & c & Measures speed of Wind \\
        \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} iv & Mausam & & d & Moving air \\
        \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user187803

Answer (score 1):

With relatively new and versatile `tabularray` package the table code is short and simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1-2, 4-5}{solid}, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l,6mm] X[l] Q[l,12mm] Q[l,6mm] X[l]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c}
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    Column A 
    &               &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Column B 
                            &                           \\
i   & Wind          &   & a & Monsoon                   \\
ii  & Anemometer    &   & b & Cyclone                   \\
iii & Hurricane, Typhoon 
                    &   & c & Measures speed of Wind    \\
iv  & Mausam        &   & d & Moving air                \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input @zarko

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
\RowStyle[bold]{}
\Block[hvlines]{*-2}{}
\Block{1-2}{Column A}
    &               &   & \Block[hvlines]{*-2}{}  
                          \Block{1-2}{Column B}       \\
i   & Wind          &   & a & Monsoon                 \\
ii  & Anemometer    &   & b & Cyclone                 \\
iii & Hurricane, Typhoon 
                    &   & c & Measures speed of Wind  \\
iv  & Mausam        &   & d & Moving air              \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]